# KeywordQuery filter by Start and End dates using Today

Tags: 2013, search, filter, keywordquery

I have a KeywordQuery that I need to filter so the current date is between the Start Date and End Date.

```
Today >= "Start Date" && Today < "End Date"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are four issues with what you are trying:

1. Your managed property names cannot have spaces in them, i.e. presuming start date and end date are your list columns, you need to find the names of managed properties associated with them.

   So your query might become like this:

   ```
   Today >= "StartDate" && Today < "EndDate"
   ```
2. You will need the order reversed for properties and the values you are comparing with.

   ```
   StartDate <= Today && EndDate > Today
   ```
3. Then you need to remove the white spaces between operators and keyword, and operators and values.

   ```
   StartDate<=Today && EndDate>Today
   ```
4. And then, you need to switch your && operator for AND.

   ```
   StartDate<=Today AND EndDate>Today
   ```

References:

[Manage search schema](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219667.aspx)

[KQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the correct syntax.  However no results are returned when I include this.  But this may now be a new question.

Comment: My answer is not complete. You need to find out the managed property names for start date and end date columns. They would most definitely not be StartDate and EndDate. They should be something like StartDateOwsDate and EndDateOwsDate. You will have to find the names from your search service application.

Comment: i posted a new question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/176252/managed-property-not-recognizing-in-querytext